# REGEX - extract multiple values from one string

Tags: regex

I am struggling to find any examples of extracting multiple values from one string using Regex, for example

*"Edit the **Expression** & **Text** to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. Undo mistakes with cmd-z. Save Favorites & Share expressions with friends or the **Community**. Explore your results with Tools. A full Reference & Help is available in the Library, or watch the video Tutorial."*

I would like to extract the following words regardless of how many times they appear in the paragraph.

```
Expression
Text
Community
```

I understand I can do this one by one, but I would like to know if I could extract all words in my list using just one Regex.

My regex for extracting one word at a time in string is;

`(?i)(expression|text|community)`

Thank you

Comment: What tool/language are you using?  Would you be satisfied just having a count of the number of occurrences of each word?

Comment: hi Julian Im working on scrapinghub.com Ideally Id like to find just once occurance of a given word tha tI can work with

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(?=.*expression)(?=.*text)(?=.*community)/igm
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, try this and could not get anything, I also stripped this down to just one word, still no joy,  Thank you for your suggestion.